# Start setInterval on mouseenter // reset on mousleave // stopping setInterval after 1 second

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, setinterval

I'm rather new to javascript and hit a wall with the follwing problem. I am trying to decrease a variable from 1000 to 0 while hovering over an element. The variable should also reset to 1000 if the mouse leaves the element.

After some research I got most of it working, but I can't figure out how to get setIntervall to stop counting after the variable reached 0. This is what I came with after looking around on stackoverflow.

```
var f = 1000, intervalId;
if (f > 0) 
{
    $(".thumb").hover(function () 
    {
        $this = $(this);
        intervalId = setInterval(function () 
        {
            $this.text(f--);
        }, 1);
    }, function () 
    {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        f = 1000;
    });
} 
else 
{
    clearInterval(intervalId);
}
```

I'm pretty sure it's a stupid mistake I am making here since I am new to programing, but if someone could point me into the right direction I would really appreciate your help.

[**FIDDLE** around with the code](http://jsfiddle.net/n74VW/55/)

Comment: What's the counter for?

Comment: I wanted to use spritely for jquery to play a png animation on some buttons. While I got it working nicely it has some useability problems in my case. Mainly the reversing of Animations and really fast hovering over the animated button. I was hoping that a variable would help me adress these issues via a setTimout delay in the calling of other functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DVPcA/

```
var f = 1000;
var interval;

$(".thumb").hover(function () {
  $this = $(this);

  interval = setInterval(function () {
    if (f > 0) {
      $this.text(f--);
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 1);
}, function () {
  clearInterval(interval);
  f = 1000;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Updated the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/n74VW/56/

replace this line

```
$this.text(f--);
```

with

```
$this.text(f>0?f--:f=0);
```

Comment: the `f>0?f--:f=0` is not really nice. why not just clear the interval?

Comment: like  SperanskyDanil said, if i e.g. check the cpu usage for chrome it will still be at 25% even it 0 is reached. that is a waste of cpu usage.

Comment: I agree, this is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/n74VW/64/ code will be $this.text(f>0?f--:(f=0,clearInterval(intervalId)));

Comment: thats why writing code that way is not so nice:  `$this.text(f>0?f--:(f=0,clearInterval(intervalId)));` will set the text to `1` when `f<=0`.  `(f=0,clearInterval(intervalId))` assigns `0` to `f` and then _returns_ the result of `clearInterval` as the value to be passed to `.text(...)` so you will only have a `0` as text when `clearInterval` returns `0`. even if i don't recommend to write it that way it should be `$this.text(f>0?f--:(clearInterval(intervalId), f=0));`